# Date in PHP +3 weeks considering the current time

Tags: php, date

Help me calculate the next sale date using PHP.

Start date January 10, 2020
Sale happens every 3 weeks on Friday.
How do I get the next sale date given the current date?

```
$start_date = "2020/01/10";
$date       = strtotime($start_date);
$date       = strtotime("+3 week", $date);
```

if current date next sale date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start_date = "2020/01/10";
$date       = strtotime($start_date);
$date       = strtotime("+3 week +1 day", $date);
$d = gmdate('Y/m/d D',$date);

while (substr($d,0,4)=="2020") {
  echo $d."\n";
  $date       = strtotime("+3 week ", $date);
  $d = gmdate('Y/m/d D',$date);
}
```

this will result in a list like this:

```
2020/01/31 Fri
2020/02/21 Fri
2020/03/13 Fri
2020/04/03 Fri
2020/04/24 Fri
2020/05/15 Fri
2020/06/05 Fri
2020/06/26 Fri
2020/07/17 Fri
2020/08/07 Fri
2020/08/28 Fri
2020/09/18 Fri
2020/10/09 Fri
2020/10/30 Fri
2020/11/20 Fri
2020/12/11 Fri
```

The `+1 day` is to correct something to do with timezones...

Comment: but how to bind the current time? time()